# is it possible that negative number to be upper bound or positive number to be lower bound of the roots of polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We know that The Upper and Lower bound Ttheorem for polynomial states:

**Theorem**

Let $f$ denote a polynomial function whose leading coefficient is positive.

• If $M > 0$ is a real number and if the third row in the process of synthetic
division of f by $x-M$ contains only numbers that are positive or zero,
then $M$ is an upper bound to the real zeros of $f$.

• If $m < 0$ is a real number and if the third row in the process of synthetic
division of $f$ by $x - m$ contains numbers that alternate positive (or $0$) and
negative (or $0$), then $m$ is a lower bound to the real zeros of $f$

From my understanding(Correct me if i'm wrong) This Theorem only tells us that the upper bound is only the positive number and the lower bound is only negative number. Is it Possible that we have the negative upper bound or maybe the positive lower bound?

Comment: This technique can only prove positive upper bounds for the real roots. This does not mean that a negative upper bound cannot exist, just that you cannot find/prove it with this theorem.

Comment: Your title talks about bounds for the polynomial itself, not for its roots.

Comment: $x+7$ and $x-7$ are both polynomials.